# Google TTS (gTTS, Python) working only once per execution

Tags: python, text-to-speech

Here's the relevant part of my code that is supposed to play back two separate strings but it only convert the first one to an audio file, saves it, plays it then my program crashes (python.exe has stopped working).

I'm running it in PyCharm on Windows 10 if that matters

```
    str1="hello"
    str2="world"

    tts = gTTS(text=str1, lang='en')
    tts.save("hello.mp3")
    playsound('hello.mp3') #works as expected till here

    tts = gTTS(text=str2, lang='en') # i believe this line is not executed properly
    tts.save("hello.mp3")
    playsound('hello.mp3')
```

i have already tried deleting the hello.mp3 file before trying to save it again ( os.remove() ).

PS: I'm very new to python so please let me know whats wrong in simple terms

Comment: can you please share code for playsound().. might be some issue in playsound() function

Comment: thats part of a package i used. https://pypi.org/project/playsound/1.2.1/

Comment: hope you are using latest playsound module.. because there was an issue with playsound https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

play sound doesn't do good! after saving use the following to play the file

`import os
     import pyglet
     tts.save(filename)
     music = pyglet.media.load(filename, streaming=False)
     music.play()
     sleep(music.duration) #prevent from killing
     os.remove(filename) #remove temperory file`

Hope this works according to what you expected!